# Different souls part of same Supreme soul?

Tags: scripture, atma, advaita, consciousness

It is said that all different souls are basically part of that one supreme soul and finally all merge into it. When a person is awakened he basically sees himself in everyone, hence doesn't criticize anyone be it the most cruel man on this planet.

My question: If we are part of same soul then does the karma of each individual soul be it bad or good affects the other souls around us in any way? Does it have any ripple effect? Any source that explains this phenomenon in details? Any scriptural references would be great.

Comment: It is more a case of each of us being associated with those who will help our jeeva live outs its karma. And on an ongoing basis our reaction to their karmas and vice versa further determine future associations. Gahana karmanyo gatih

Comment: The explanation AFAIK requires that *merging* be well-defined.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Soul merges with Supreme Soul which was the ultimate goal of meditation....merger here means becomes one.

Comment: OK, the concept of non-difference between soul and supreme soul in the state of moksha is an advaitic one. It may then help to ask for answers conditioned on this by explicitly mentioning in the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

Both the Supreme Lord and the living entity are known as atma. The Supreme Lord is called Paramatma, and the living entity is called the jivatma,  or  jiva as mentioned in [**Brahma Sutras**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras/d/doc62776.html)  and  [**Upanishads**](http://estudantedavedanta.net/Svetasvatara_Upanishad%20-%20Swami%20Tyagisananda%20%281949%29%20[Sanskrit-English].pdf) below. See Page no. 82.

> गुहां प्रविष्टावात्मानौ हि, तद्दर्शनात् ॥ Sutra 1,2.11 ॥
>
> guhāṃ praviṣṭāvātmānau hi, taddarśanāt ||
>
> The two that have entered into the cavity (of the heart) are indeed the individual self and the Supreme Self, because it is so
>   seen.
>
> ---
>
> द्वा सुपर्णा सयुजा सखाया समानं वृक्षं परिषस्वजाते ।  तयोरन्यः पिप्पलं
>   स्वाद्वत्त्यनश्नन्नन्यो अभिचाकशीति ॥ १ ॥
>
> dvā suparṇā sayujā sakhāyā samānaṃ vṛkṣaṃ pariṣasvajāte |  tayoranyaḥ
>   pippalaṃ svādvattyanaśnannanyo abhicākaśīti || 1 ||
>
> Two birds of beautiful plumage , who are inseparable friends , reside
>   on the self same tree . OF these one eats the fruits of the tree with
>   relish ,while the other looks on without eating.

---

The relative answer is provided in  Parashar Gita found in  - [**Mahabharata Shanti Parva**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b118.htm) -Moksha Dharma Parva - Chapter 291 - Verse  no. 22.  Where Rishi Parashara is explaining King janaka about your question. The meaning of the below verse is that no one Jivatma can affect other jivatma by his karmas , One jivatma can not get affected by good or bad deeds of another jivatma.He only  himself suffers or enjoys the fruits of his actions and those can not affect other one.

> नायं परस्य सुकृतं दृष्क्रुतं चापि सेवते |
>    करोति यादृशं कर्म तादृशं
>   प्रतिपद्यते || 22||
>
> One never has to enjoy or endure the good and bad acts of another.
>   Indeed, one enjoys and endures the fruits of only those acts that one
>   does oneself. **p. 347**

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ... jivatama resides in each individual so where does the Paramatma reside?

Comment: @Just_Do_It Jivatma is nothing but a reflection of ParmAtma on maya Tattva

Comment: @Rohit. Yes and the Brahman is everywhere , there is no place in this universe where he is not."Sarvam Khalvidam Brahma" & at the same time he resides in Jivatma.